# Android SQLite query causing many skipped frames

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, sqlite, retrofit

I'm making a few retrofit calls, 4 to be precise, and inside each of these calls I'm storing it's results into a SQLite database, my problem is, these storage queries have usually around 800 entries to save into the database, so it takes a few seconds and it is making the app skip about 300 frames.

So I've searched and found out that the retrofit calls are made in another thread, but it's onResponse, and onFailure are handled by the main thread.

I'm afraid that if I put 4 asyncTasks running on the same time, it wold make the app slow in the same way, am I right? Also because on the end of the Sqlite query I perform a test to determine if that was the last query and show a success message. Any suggestions?

Final working code:

```
Call<List<Cadastro>> callCadastro = cadastroApi.getCadastro(token);
callCadastro.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cadastro>>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<List<Cadastro>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

    final List<Cadastro> cadastroList = response.body();

        if (cadastroList != null) {

            class CadastroAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

                @Override
                protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    try {

                        RepositorioCadastro repositorioCadastro = new RepositorioCadastro(conn);

                        // Insere cada item da lista no Banco de dados
                        for (Cadastro c : cadastroList) {

                            repositorioCadastro.inserirCadastro(c);

                            // Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Cadastro inserido ID: " + c.getId());

                        }

                    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                        Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro ao inserir Cadastro(s) no banco de dados local: " + e.getMessage());

                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {

                    // Incrementa o contador para verificar se abre ou não a caixa de dialogo de sucesso
                    contador++;

                    if (contador == 4) {

                        //Aumenta o progresso da janela de Dialogo
                        progressDialog.incrementProgress(28);
                        Log.i("CONTADOR", "Contador Cadastros: " + contador);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();// Dispensa a barra de progresso
                        // Janela de dialogo que abre a activity login
                        MessageBox.showAlertToken(TokenActivity.this, "Sincronizado com sucesso", "Pressione OK para continuar");

                    } else {
                        //Aumenta o progresso da janela de Dialogo
                        progressDialog.incrementProgress(28);
                        contador++;
                        Log.i("CONTADOR", "Contador Cadastros else: " + contador);

                    }
                }
            }

            // Executa a asyncTask
            new CadastroAsyncTask().execute();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro retrofit ao baixar Cadastros: " + t.getMessage());

    }

});
```

Previous code:

```
Call<List<Cadastro>> callCadastro = cadastroApi.getCadastro(token);
callCadastro.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cadastro>>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<List<Cadastro>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

    List<Cadastro> cadastroList = response.body();

        if (cadastroList != null) {

            try {

                RepositorioCadastro repositorioCadastro = new RepositorioCadastro(conn);

                    // Inserts each item of the list in the sqlite database
                    for (Cadastro c : cadastroList) {

                        repositorioCadastro.inserirCadastro(c);

                    }

                } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                     // On Sqlite Failure
                     Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro ao inserir Cadastro(s) no banco de dados local: " + e.getMessage());

                } finally {

                    // Increments the counter to test if it is the last query to finish
                    contador++;

                    if (contador == 4) {

                        // If is the last query to finish, opens the message box

                        //Increases the progress in a MaterialDialog progressDialog
                        progressDialog.incrementProgress(28);
                        Log.i("CONTADOR", "Contador Cadastros: " + contador);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();// Dispensa a barra de progresso
                        // When click OK in the message box, start a new activity
                        MessageBox.showAlertToken(TokenActivity.this, "Sincronizado com sucesso", "Pressione OK para continuar");

                    } else {
                        //Increases the progress in a MaterialDialog progressDialog
                        progressDialog.incrementProgress(28);
                        contador++;
                        Log.i("CONTADOR", "Contador Cadastros else: " + contador);

                    }
                }

        }

}

@Override
// On Retrofit Failure
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro retrofit ao baixar Cadastros: " + t.getMessage());

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm afraid that if I put 4 asyncTasks running on the same time, it wold make the slow in the same way, am I right?

You are wrong. It is completly different if you do your database work on the UI Thread or in any other thread:
If you don't do it on the UI Thread, your App will stay responsive. Your User can work with your app.
If you do it on the UI Thread, you will skip frames. Your user won't be able to use your app during this time.
After 5 seconds of unresponsive UI the system will even show a ANR (Application not responding) message to the user, asking him to exit the app.

You suggested to use an Asynctask. This should be the right way, please try it.
You can handle your counter (`contador`) inside "doInBackground" and `publishProgress`.
Both `Asynctask.onProgressUpdate` and `Asynctask.onPostExecute` run on the UI thread, so you can safely update your UI here and inform your user.

Comment: Tank you so much! After much thinking on how to handle the errors, it worked perfectly! I'm gonna add some of the new code in case it could help anyone else.